# Transpose (rotate) data from datatable column to rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

Let' say we have the following table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Value 4 | Value 7 | 10.0 |
| Value 2 | Value 5 | Value 8 | 10.0 |
| Value 3 | Value 6 | Value 9 | 69.47 |

I would like to have something like this if the user selects `Col4` (or any other column, this is just an example) from the select:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Col4: 10.00** |  |  |
| Value 1 | Value 4 | Value 7 |
| Value 2 | Value 5 | Value 8 |
| **Col4: 69.47** |  |  |
| Value 3 | Value 6 | Value 9 |

[LIVE DATATABLES DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/tanolize/1/)

I've been searching for hours and couldn't find anything neither in the official documentation, nor in the plugins, nor in the previous stack overflow questions.

[Some people suggest you could rotate via css the datatable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/101974/#Comment_101974), but the thread it's a bit old and I haven't got it to work for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

With css only I am not sure whether this is possible entirely but with jquery, you can dynamically add rows to the data table [example added here](http://live.datatables.net/tanolize/4/) (this is just for ideation the code can be cleaned up further)

Also to add the rows in particular index is based upon the ordering conditions applied to the table. ([Official documentation is here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29147/put-new-rows-at-the-specific-position-of-the-jquery-datatable))

However there is a concept of row grouping in data table ([example official link here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html))

So by getting selected column data dynamically([follow link 1](http://live.datatables.net/tanolize/4/))
and then grouping as row headers ([follow link 3](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)), you can get your desired result.